# What is a postgresql's query to solve these quite complicated steps?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, postgis

stackoverflow.

This may be challenged question because it is included the PostGIS function to calculate the missing data (the_geom) for each asset according to the old data we have. Whether you know PostGIS or not, you may solve this question.

- (note) I know exactly what I wanted from this question, but I don't know the STEPS to merge all of this in to a single query or in a PHP script.*

Let me explain some details of the question.
First, think about the bike lane (asset) on the street. The bike lane itself is a linestring and is located in one or many sub-street (*sub-ctrl-section*).

To visualize this problem, these are some possible results.

```
==============|=============
x---------------------y

==============|======|==========
   x-------------------------y

==============
    x------y
```

> Note : 
>   "=======" is cid(each *sub-ctrl-section*), "|" separate each cid,
>   "-------" is aid(each assets),"x" is km_start (starting point), "y" is km_end (ending point) of each assets.

asset (Table) -- contains 5 assets

```
aid | km_start | km_end | ctrl_sec_no | the_geom
1 | 10 | 15 | 1234 | null
2 | 10 | 25 | 1234 | null
3 | 13 | 15 | 5678 | null
4 | 11 | 15 | 5678 | null
5 | 13 | 17 | 5678 | null
```

centerline (Table) -- contain 5 *sub-ctrl-sections*.

```
 cid | km_start | km_end | ctrl_sec_no | the_geom(LINESTRING)
   1 | 10 | 12 | 1234 | xxxx...
   2 | 13 | 15 | 1234 | xxxx...
   3 | 16 | 30 | 1234 | xxxx...
   4 | 10 | 15 | 5678 | xxxx...
   5 | 16 | 20 | 5678 | xxxx...
```

I want the result to be like

```
aid(1) -> cid(1) + cid(2)
aid(2) -> cid(1) + cid(2) + cid(3)
aid(3) -> cid(4)
aid(4) -> cid(4)
aid(5) -> cid(4) + cid(5)
```

note : "asset(1) is contain in centerline(1) and centerline(2) in term of cid"

Then, after we get every cid(centerline) from the step above, we want to **UPDATE** the_geom of each aid(assets) by using "[ST_Line_Substring](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Line_Substring.html)" to find Substring of each cid we get.

But now we don't have the_geom for asset(Table), so we have to calculate it!

For example (ctrl_sec_no:1234) -- this is not perfect scale, just for visualization

```
10======12======13======15======16======30
x-------|-------|-------y (aid:1)
x-------|-------|-------------------y (aid:2)
                x-------y (aid:3)
```

For example (ctrl_sec_no:5678)

```
10=====15/16=====20
  x-----y (aid:4)
     x--|----y (aid:5)
```

That means we have to calculate the RATIO of the asset in each *sub-ctrl-sections* by using ST_Line_Substring. Now, we will show how this function works :)

For example: (aid:5) occupied in 2 *sub-ctrl-sections*

```
SELECT ST_Line_Substring('the_geom',13-10/15-10,1.0) FROM centerline WHERE ctrl_sec_id = 4567 and cid = 4

SELECT ST_Line_Substring('the_geom',0.0,17-16/20-16) FROM centerline WHERE ctrl_sec_id = 4567 and cid = 5
```

(13-10)/(15-10) = 3/5 is the RATIO of (aid:5)'s 1st part of the asset which occupied in (cid:4)  -- a.km_start - c.km_start / c.km_end - c.km_start

(17-16)/(20-16) = 1/4 is the RATIO of (aid:5)'s 2nd part of the asset which occupied in (cid:5)  -- a.km_start - c.km_start / c.km_end - c.km_start

Then we have to ST_Union each parts (the_geom that is returned from ST_Line_Substring) we calculate from above queries.

The question is what is the query to do all these steps, these may be done with PHP script if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table asset (
    aid integer primary key, 
    km_start integer not null, 
    km_end integer not null, 
    ctrl_sec_no integer not null, 
    the_geom text default null
)
;

insert into asset (aid, km_start, km_end, ctrl_sec_no)
values
(1, 10, 15, 1234),
(2, 10, 25, 1234),
(3, 10, 12, 5678), 
(4, 11, 15, 5678),
(5, 13, 17, 5678)
;

create table centerline (
    cid integer primary key, 
    km_start integer not null, 
    km_end integer not null, 
    ctrl_sec_no integer not null, 
    the_geom text not null default 'xxxx...'
)
;

insert into centerline (cid, km_start, km_end, ctrl_sec_no)
values
(1, 10, 12, 1234),
(2, 13, 15, 1234),
(3, 16, 30, 1234),
(4, 10, 15, 5678),
(5, 16, 17, 5678)
;

select aid, cid
from asset a
inner join centerline c on 
    a.ctrl_sec_no = c.ctrl_sec_no
    and (
        a.km_start between c.km_start and c.km_end
        or
        a.km_end between c.km_start and c.km_end
        or
        a.km_start <= c.km_start and a.km_end >= c.km_end
        )
order by aid, cid
;

 aid | cid 
-----+-----
   1 |   1
   1 |   2
   2 |   1
   2 |   2
   2 |   3
   3 |   4
   4 |   4
   5 |   4
   5 |   5
(9 rows)
```

I don't understand the second part of your question. Could you detail it?

Comment: i have updated the question's detail, please check, thanks for your great co-op :)